# How to log tomcat session invalidation or user logout

Tags: java, session, tomcat, logging, spring-security

How can I log situation when tomcat 7 invalidate session or when user is logged out from application because of expired session or wrong session at all. For example user sign in into webapp, he gets his jsessionid a saves it into browser cookies, then I manually invalidate session through the tomcat manager or delete jsessionid from cookies. Both of cases cause user logout but I think that this behaviour handles tomcat itselves so, i have to catch this invokation somewhere in tomcat. How can I do this?

I need this because of problem with random invalidation of session, which could be cause maybe with bad clustering (we have two nodes with sticky session) or maybe garbagge collector destroying our session but It could anything else, so I need some wider context.

I use tomcat 7, java 1.7, jsf 1.2, spring-security 3

Thank you

Comment: There's a listener for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement an HttpSessionListener, put your logging code on the sessionDestroyed method,  and register it on your web.xml file.

Here's an example:

http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/

Comment: Note that the example is somewhat dated - this can all be done with annotations now. No need to any `web.xml`.